# Plesk scheduled task not working

Tags: php, plesk, cron

I've got some problems with the scheduled task feature in Plesk while setting up a task that should execute a php-file every minute. [image: screenshot]

As you can see in the screenshot, everything should be fine and executing the task seems successfully completed. The php-script contains one line of code:

`file_put_contents('./test.txt', date("d.m.Y H:i:s"), FILE_APPEND);`

So it writes the current date and time to the file, cool. If i open that file directly in my browser (`http://example.com/test.php`) it works (`test.txt` is writeable with 777)

But it doesn't work automatically (every minute) and also fails when trying to hit the "Execute now"-button in Plesk (see screenshot, bottom left button). Obviously I see a success-message, but nothing happened (`test.txt` does not contain new content and time of last modification does not change).

Comment: Ensure emails send every time script runs - not just on errors. Ensure error handling/debug on script is output - you will get that then in an email. Might help you drill down to problem.

Comment: @user29671 i set display_errors an error_reporting to output all errors but nothing happens. I also sent an email in my php-script, this works too. But it wont write content to the test.txt...

Comment: I would be ensuring the script works in the most basic form by cron - eg example one here > http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: Does it ever write to that file? Files in the document root should not be writeable (the directory itself also needs to be writeable) as this is a security risk. Also, in the context of the command line, what does `./` refer to?

Comment: It's great that you solved this, however the title shouldn't be edited to reflect that. It would be better instead if you or @user29671 answered this below so it's clearer to others, and then you can accept that.

Comment: @dan i thought it would be easier for others when I edit the title.

Comment: I understand, how we indicate something has been solved here is by accepting an answer, so it's clear what that is to others. It's perfectly fine for you to answer it yourself too, and accept that when you can.

Comment: SOLVED the mystery. The code worked but the test.txt was created in a parent folder because the environment of the executing user was used for ./ and not the path of the php script. So it worked all the time ... damn^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated the issue on a PLESK 12 node and solved it.

```
file_put_contents('**./test.txt**', date("d.m.Y H:i:s"), FILE_APPEND);
```

**Apply the full path to the PHP file for the output script:**

The PHP file:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/webroot/test.txt', date(" 'd.m.Y H:i:s' "), FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Output after 3 Crons:

```
'07.04.2016 02:41:32'  '07.04.2016 02:41:40'  '07.04.2016 02:42:01'
```

With the `./test.txt` path it was only able to write one time - with the full path its writing every cron.